# Laravel 5.4 loads welcome page once, then errors out. What's going on?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to learn Laravel, but it's not working. As the title indicates, I can load the install laravel (via `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`) and run `php artisan serve` and I get the welcome screen. The issue is that it literally only loads once. I don't even have to make any changes to anything, and if I refresh the page I get a huge stack trace.

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
(1/1) FatalThrowableError

Call to undefined function Illuminate\Session\ctype_alnum()
in Store.php (line 557)
at Store->isValidId('YffDpw0QPtFWQR1ax2IoLUxS7BDl2WLhRrw2XEQg')in Store.php (line 546)
at Store->setId('YffDpw0QPtFWQR1ax2IoLUxS7BDl2WLhRrw2XEQg')in StartSession.php (line 116)
at StartSession->Illuminate\Session\Middleware\{closure}(object(Store))in helpers.php (line 950)
at tap(object(Store), object(Closure))in StartSession.php (line 117)
at StartSession->getSession(object(Request))in StartSession.php (line 100)
at StartSession->startSession(object(Request))in StartSession.php (line 58)
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php (line 37)
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in EncryptCookies.php (line 59)
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php (line 102)
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))in Router.php (line 576)
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request))in Router.php (line 535)
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request))in Router.php (line 513)
at Router->dispatch(object(Request))in Kernel.php (line 176)
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php (line 30)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in TransformsRequest.php (line 30)
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in TransformsRequest.php (line 30)
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in ValidatePostSize.php (line 27)
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php (line 46)
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))in Pipeline.php (line 102)
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))in Kernel.php (line 151)
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request))in Kernel.php (line 116)
at Kernel->handle(object(Request))in index.php (line 53)
at require_once('/home/jonathan/Dropbox/Projects/laravel/blog/public/index.php')in server.php (line 21)
```

I've run the following commands to try to remedy the problem

```
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

and I still don't get a welcome page again.

I'm running Laravel Framework 5.4.33 on php7 on openSUSE Tumbleweed.

What to do?

Comment: Missing file? Maybe Laravel isn't loading that Session class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the PHP [ctype extension](http://php.net/manual/en/ctype.setup.php)

Do check the Laravel docs to ensure that you install all [required PHP extensions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#server-requirements)

Comment: That fixed it. I'll accept the answer when I can. I didn't see the extensions listed in the page you linked, but I'll do some more searching.